# tcp message communications

Tags: c, process, tcp, send, recv

hi i want to use tcp connection to send/recv messages. The question is i want to send many messages and measure the latencies. Thus, I don't want to receive after every message sent. However, if i don't handle incoming messages in time, the program alway get unexpected result. Is there any way that I can handle recv() without blocking my program of sending msg?
Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measuring latency using TCP is maybe not the optimal idea, since TCP necessarily *introduces* latency of its own (see [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)). TCP is meant as a byte stream, it doesn't have a well-defined idea of "messages" even.

You can set the socket to be [non-blocking](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket), which will cause `recv()` to return immediately if there is no data. If you don't want to waste CPU by polling, you can instead use `select()` to detect when the socket has data available for reading.

Comment: +1. UDP would be a better choice here. Perhaps the OQ was just using "TCP" as a (unfortunate) synonym for "sockets".

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am measuring the latency particularly for the tcp connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select()` to test whether incoming data is available.

Answer (score 0):

One option I haven't seen mentioned here would be to use a spearate thread for receives. That way you can make your simple dumb blocking waits without interfering (much) with your send logic in the other thread.